# How to get a copy of rows until it reaches a certain point

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a code where I need to create a copy of each row if the 'Date_Numerical' is under 30.5 (average days per month). What I would like is to subtract the 'Date_Numerical' by 30 until the column value for the 'SCU_KEY' is under 30.5. Here is the code I used that would create one copy and an example dataframe, but not more than one:

```
def func(row):
   if row['Date_Numerical'] > 30:
        row2 = row.copy()
        return pd.concat([row, row2], axis=1)
   return row

df_2 = pd.concat([func(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True, axis=1).T
```

```
Original output:

df = pd.DataFrame({'SCU_KEY':         [3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Date_Numerical':  [70, 20, 15, 110]})

Desired Output:

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'SCU_KEY':        [3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6],
                     'Date_Numerical': [70, 40, 10, 20, 15, 110, 80, 50, 20]})
```

Comment: "subtract the 'Date_Numerical' by 30.5 *until the column value for the 'SCU_KEY' is under 30.5*". What do you mean by this? Your function does not do anything but copy rows and your desired output shows rows subtracted by 30 (not 30.5).

Comment: Sorry I changed it to 30 to make it more simple. Just thinking of the average days per month but for now we could just focus on 30. I want to see if I could create a return value that subtracts each value in 'Date_Numerical' by 30 until it reaches a certain point (sort of like a trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `apply` and `explode`:

```
df["Date_Numerical"] = df["Date_Numerical"].apply(lambda x: list(range(x, 0, -30)))
df = df.explode("Date_Numerical").reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df
   SCU_KEY Date_Numerical
0        3             70
1        3             40
2        3             10
3        4             20
4        5             15
5        6            110
6        6             80
7        6             50
8        6             20
```

If you want a difference of 30.5, you could use:

```
df["Date_Numerical"] = df["Date_Numerical"].apply(lambda x: [i/10 for i in range(x*10, 0, -305)])
df = df.explode("Date_Numerical").reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df
   SCU_KEY Date_Numerical
0        3           70.0
1        3           39.5
2        3            9.0
3        4           20.0
4        5           15.0
5        6          110.0
6        6           79.5
7        6           49.0
8        6           18.5
```